# Ping problem CMSIS Stm32f10x with UDP

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, network-interface, cmsis

Here is my program:

```
int32_t socket;
uint8_t *sendbuf;

void SetSCK(){  

            socket = netUDP_GetSocket(udp_cb_func);
            if (socket >= 0) 
            {
                    netUDP_Open(socket,0);
                    netUDP_SetOption (socket, netUDP_OptionTTL, 20);
            }
}

void Time3(void){
TIM_TimeBaseInitTypeDef TimeStruct; 
NVIC_InitTypeDef nvicStructure;

NVIC_PriorityGroupConfig(NVIC_PriorityGroup_3);
nvicStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel = TIM3_IRQn;
nvicStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority =1;
nvicStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 0;
nvicStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;
NVIC_Init(&nvicStructure);      

RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_TIM3,ENABLE);
TimeStruct.TIM_Prescaler=35;
TimeStruct.TIM_Period=200;  ///200=100us
TimeStruct.TIM_ClockDivision=TIM_CKD_DIV1;  
TimeStruct.TIM_CounterMode= TIM_CounterMode_Up ;
TIM_TimeBaseInit(TIM3, &TimeStruct);
TIM_Cmd(TIM3, ENABLE);
TIM_ITConfig(TIM3,TIM_IT_Update,ENABLE);
}

/*###########################################
##############Main Function##################
###########################################*/ 


int main (void){
    CLOCK();
    GPIO_SetBits(GPIOA,GPIO_Pin_5);
    LongDelay();
    netInitialize();
    LongDelay();
    Time3();
    GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOA,GPIO_Pin_5);

    do {
    osDelay(500U);
    netIF_GetOption(NET_IF_CLASS_ETH | 0, netIF_OptionIP4_Address, (uint8_t *)&addr, sizeof (addr));
    } while (addr == 0U);



    SetSCK();


    while (1) 

    {

        if(Alarm==1)
        {
            Alarm=0;
            Ethers();
        }



    }
}

void Ethers(void)
{
            NET_ADDR addrUDP={ NET_ADDR_IP4, 5022, 192, 168,1,10};
            if(socket>=0){
            CheckAlarm=0;
            Data();
            sendbuf =  netUDP_GetBuffer (Ether.Size);
            memcpy (sendbuf, MSG, Ether.Size);
            State=netUDP_Send (socket,&addrUDP,sendbuf,Ether.Size); 
}

void TIM3_IRQHandler(){

    Alarm=1;
    TIM_ClearITPendingBit(TIM3, TIM_IT_Update);
}
```

This program has two main problems:

1) It sends 16bytes each 100 microS, during its transmission it doesn't respond to ping command while it sends data correctly.
[image]
2)Sometimes, it stops working for checking its IP has been set correctly

```
    do {
    osDelay(500U);
    netIF_GetOption(NET_IF_CLASS_ETH | 0, netIF_OptionIP4_Address, (uint8_t *)&addr, sizeof (addr));
    } while (addr == 0U);
```

I will be grateful if you could help me.

Comment: ping (icmp) and udp (ip) are not related.  do you need to setup icmp as well, I have not used this part of the library (yet).  if you are getting and/or sending packets then arp is working as one would expect for a IP/UDP stack but I would expect ICMP to be a separate deal.

Comment: Thank you, I checked an it seems there is no function to handle Png ICMP pakcages manually.